# HttpAddUrl permissions

Tags: c++, windows, security, networking, winhttp

I'm trying to run a custom WinHTTP based web-server on Windows Server 2008 machine.

I pass "http://*:22222/" to HttpAddUrl

When I start my executable as Administrator or LocalSystem everything works fine. However if I try to run it as NetworkService to minimize security risks (since there are no legitimate reasons for the app to use admin rights) function fails with "Access Denied" error code.

I wasn't aware of NetworkService having any restrictions on which ports and interfaces it can listen on.

Is there a way to configure permissions in such a way so that I actually can run the app under NetworkService account and connect to it from other internet hosts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be an administrator to add URLs to the http.sys URL mappings. Network Service does is not a member of the admin group, but the admnistrator's group and the System account are members.

IIS gets around this by having one process, inetinfo.exe, that runs as SYSTEM and sets up the URL mappings for worker processes (w3wp.exe) that run as Network Service.

Hope that clarifies tings.

Comment: The corrollory to this is that you will probably want your installer to add the mapping when the service is installed, or supply a standalone configuration tool that does the same thing.

I bumped into this exact problem earlier this week and (after some googling) found this standalone app which created the mapping for me: http://urlreservation.codeplex.com/

Comment: This tool was exactly what I needed! I glanced inside source code it looks like those who want to create these mappings from their code should google 'HttpSetServiceConfiguration' function